# APT doesn't remove Nginx and all related packages with $ sudo apt autoremove --purge nginx

Tags: apt, apache2, nginx

I installed Nginx with just the package name 'nginx', so I'd think that if I autoremoved it, it'd also remove nginx-common, nginx-full and the libnginx's, because I tried installing (which also automatically starts) Apache2 afterwards and it failed to start. Autoremoving nginx-common and nginx-full removed the rest. APT also wanted to install new stuff while removing which I thought was odd be there's probably a reason.

Comment: Why APT autoremove doesn't remove everything related to Nginx to simply the process of removing it. Is it a design choice even if inconvenient?

Comment: Yes, please put your explicit question [in your Question above](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1276369/edit). Edit your question to refine and improve it; not comments.

Comment: The usual reason is that some other package depended upon the remaining packages, so they were not eligible for autoremoval. Apt trying to replace uninstalled packages with alternatives is usually this reason. Another common reason is that you specified some of the packages when you installed; specified packages are ineligible for autoremoval. There are other possible reasons. Without additional data, you are asking us to speculate.

Comment: This also happened months ago when I was trying to autoremove Apache2, as I had only installed 'apache2' with no other specific package mentions, and then I had to autoremove a few leftovers after maybe an hour of not knowing why Nginx was failing to start (Apache was still using the port Nginx was trying to use).

Comment: Same possible reasons.

Comment: Regarding your first reason, I was still able to delete the missed packages right afterwards so it's probably not that. Interestingly though, this time, autoremoving Apache2 deleted everything like it should, unlike last time. Unless I post my Bash log, idk how to how else to check if it's something I did or not.

Comment: Oh, it's clearly something you did. But to determine exactly what you did, we would need to see the exact commands that you used to install and remove all relevant packages, and the relevant apt term.log sections to see the system output from each command.

Comment: I've been using apt for 15 years. It has more than four variables, so a human mind can easily lose track. But it's logic is still fairly simple.

Comment: Read `man apt`. You are misunderstanding `autoremove`.

Comment: Probably. Do you know if apt is supposed to remove Nginx, nginx-common and nginx-core if the only Nginx or server-related package I installed was 'nginx' with no other specific package, with `autoremove nginx`?